# Values from header are empty when MimeMessage is created using a file

Tags: java, scala, jakarta-mail, email-headers, mime-message

When i create a MimeMessage using a file, all my headers values are empty but when i run as debug and check variable "line" inside Header, it's correct.

Here is what my debug shows inside mimemessage.getAllHeaders():

```
[10]    InternetHeaders$InternetHeader  (id=219)    
    line    "MessageId:12335" (id=234)  
    name    "MessageId" (id=235)    
    value   "" (id=232)
```

My file looks like it:

```
Received: by 10.140.28.117 with 
HTTP; Tue, 15 Jul 2014 04:34:44 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Tue, 15 Jul 2014 08:34:44 -0300
MessageId:1234
Delivered-To: lore@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CA+V+8yMuUKkiwFjysSVjmSQ2UJ5L_B4JrEt8afyugUQW_cbmMg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
From: David L <lore@gmail.com>
To: David L <lore@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=047d7b604a1c4c255404fe39cbf3

--047d7b604a1c4c255404fe39cbf3
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

test email message

--047d7b604a1c4c255404fe39cbf3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">test email message<br></div>

--047d7b604a1c4c255404fe39cbf3--
```

And here is how i get my object:

```
 var is = new FileInputStream(file)
 var session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties())
 var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session, is)
```

Any idea why Value is empty?

Thank in advance.

David

Comment: What library are you using? javax.mail?

Comment: Yes! Now i'm using Mime4J for workaround this problem. But the problem happens on javax.Mail.

Comment: Where are the `line`, `name` and `value` variables being set up? Also, for processing email in Scala using JavaMail you might try Courier (https://github.com/softprops/courier). It provides a much nicer idiomatic interface.

Comment: Those variables comes from file that i've posted on topic ( "MessageId:1234" ). I've checked the Courier but it looks like that i can not build a message using a file and i need build a message from text file to get body. I don't want to do a regex or something similar to get separate body and headers.

Comment: You've posted this message to at least three different forums/mailing lists.  I answered it on the [JavaMail users mailing list](https://java.net/projects/javamail/lists/users/archive/2014-07/message/1), I'm not going to answer it again here.

Comment: @BillShannon i saw your email, buddy. I'm going to answer it right now.

Comment: Solved. Problem was with the loop iterating.

Comment: @BillShannon turns out that better to answer here than there ;)

Comment: For reference here is the mail archive: http://download.oracle.com/javaee-archive/javamail.java.net/users/2014/07/index.html